# Custom module permission option not available

Tags: 6, users

I developed a custom module and enabled it from admin panel `https://site/administer/modules/list` . But at *permissions* page `https://site/admin/user/permissions` there is no option for the administer or other users to enable it.

[image]

As you can see my custom module named is *notification module* but there is no option to add permission for that.

**Edit**

I have *hook_perm* as follows

```
function hook_perm() {
  return array(
    'access GA admin tab',
    'access check backend tab',
    'access GA admin menus',
    'access GA autocompletion',
    'bypass GA field verification',
  );
}
```

Is there any relevance for this to the administer permission?

**Update**

My bad , i was given the same hook_permission values in another module , so it got overwritten with the other module , and my module permission got freezed !

Comment: can you show us your implementation of permission hook? ( hook_perm in D6, hook_permission in D7 )

Comment: Add your code to question ( hook_perm)

Comment: it seems to ok, did you try clear the cache?

Comment: Yes , but i have a doubt , once i disabled 'disable all developer modules' below the clear cache menu .

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich permission is one of the things Drupal cache it, try to enable disable the module ( also uninstall it completely ) and then try to clear the cache

Comment: Is there anything to clear in db , for permission cache

Answer (score 1):

Here is to implement the hook permission

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer your module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer permission for your module'),
      'description' => t('Some description that would appear on the permission page..'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer applies to Drupal 7 -- the question is tagged for Drupal 6.